# Multiple subqueries on same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One contains details about an object, and the other contains the dimensions of that object. What I'm trying to do is get all objects with a certain set of dimensions.

I've got half way there with this query

```
SELECT object_key, (SELECT dbo.getDimensionString(object_key)) FROM objectTable 
WHERE object_key IN (SELECT object_key FROM dimensionsTable WHERE value > 90 AND value < 200) 
AND object_key IN (SELECT object_key FROM dimensionsTable WHERE value = 20)
AND object_key IN (SELECT object_key FROM dimensionsTable WHERE value = 10)
```

This code works fine as long as all the dimensions are the different. The problem is that when two (or more) of the dimensions i'm searching for are the same, it matches other records too. For example a search for '100 x 100 x 20' this will match objects like '100 x 200 x 20'

The dimensions table looks something like this:

```
dimension_key, object_key, value
1,1,100
2,1,100
3,1,20

4,2,100
5,2,200
6,2,20

7,3,150
8,3,100
9,3,20
```

I want to search for the results >90 <200, >90 <200, and 20. To which the result would be 1 and 3

How can i change my code to avoid this?

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.  There are undoubtedly other columns that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do what you want with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select object_key, dbo.getDimensionString(object_key)
from dimensionsTable
where (value > 90 and value < 200) and
      (value = 20) and (value = 10)
group by object_key
having count(*) = 3;
```

Note the `count(*) = 3` requires that there be three matches among the values.  So, this assumes that the dimensions table contains three dimensions for each object.

I should note that the query is a little bit different for your final case -- you don't want 100,100,20 to match 100,20,20.  So:

```
select object_key, dbo.getDimensionString(object_key)
from dimensionsTable
where value in (100, 20)
group by object_key
having sum(case when value = 100 then 1 else 0 end) = 2 and
       sum(case when value = 20 then 1 else 0 end) = 1;
```

This form of the `having` clause is actually the more general solution.

Comment: The second SQL accomplishes the task! 
But, is there anyway to change it to be able to search for ranges as well?

Comment: Take the first query but use OR in between the comparisons. The AND condition is impossible.

Comment: Thanks! i figured it out xD!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd post my solution here in case it is of any use to anyone.

The solution provided by Gordon did work, but only as long as none of the conditions overlapped, which sometimes happened in my system. So i ended up doing this:

```
SELECT dimensionsTable.objectTable_key, dbo.getDimensionString(dimensionsTable.objectTable_key) 
FROM (SELECT b.objectTable_key, b.dimension_key 
        FROM(SELECT c.objectTable_key, c.dimension_key 
            FROM(SELECT d.objectTable_key, d.dimension_key 
                    FROM dimensionsTable d WHERE (value >= 100 AND value <= 110)) c 
            JOIN dimensionsTable ON dimensionsTable.objectTable_key = c.objectTable_key  
            WHERE (value >= 100 AND value <= 110) AND dimensionsTable.dimension_key <> c.dimension_key) b
    JOIN dimensionsTable ON dimensionsTable.objectTable_key = b.objectTable_key  
    WHERE (value >= 10 AND value <= 20) AND dimensionsTable.dimension_key <> b.dimension_key) a 
JOIN dimensionsTable ON dimensionsTable.objectTable_key = a.objectTable_key 
WHERE (value >= 210 AND value <= 220) AND dimensionsTable.dimension_key <> a.dimension_key 
GROUP BY dimensionsTable.objectTable_key
```

If anyone knows a simpler way to write this, i'd be interested :).

Comment: Someone posted a much easier solution as an answer 5 hours before you posted this.  The posted answer is also faster / more efficient than this is.